# Content of <input type=file> to SQL Server

Tags: javascript, file, input, types

Good afternoon.

In javascript, I have filled an input type=file multiple with different images.
My question is how can I now send these images to store them in SQL Server?.

This is my code generated in html by javascript, and I don't know how to go through the <input> image by image to treat it in bytes and store it in an image field of the SQL Server table

[image]

I would appreciate if you could tell me in an example how to treat it on the server side to store it.
Thanks

Comment: You need a server-side language like PHP, NodeJS, Python, etc. to handle the form data (and to make the db connection and store things in it).

Comment: Yes thanks, I have the connection to the database established and I use the VB in visual studio.
Where I will not continue is on the server side how to access the content of the input to go through it and convert the bytes that make up the images to store them in the database table